# Quality loss when exporting on Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere

I'm having some trouble when exporting a sequence in Adobe Premiere CS6. There is a quality loss: image are more pixelated and colors are more bland.
I'm exporting in H.264 format and it's 1920x1080 footage. I tried every possibility of configurations and it keep exporting less good quality.

Here are some screenshots, so you can compare the original quality and what comes out from exportation:

[image: Original footage]

[image: Quality loss when exporting in Premiere]

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Use a visually lossless (intermediary) codec when going between different editing applications. Avid DNxHR, Apple Prores, Edius HQX, and GoPro Cineform are all examples of intermediary codecs. I personally prefer DNxHR, but all the options I listed are good options.

You can also use dynamic link between After Effects and Premiere, which would be even better.

Comment: I only use one editing application which is Premiere. So I don't think that's where the problem is... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's not a playback issue. Different players may show differences in gamma etc., you can see it for yourself when opening a h264 encoded clip in QuickTime vs. VLC vs. Flash based player in a Browser. Did you take the Screenshots in the same player when comparing original vs exported material?

Comment: Yes, I did ! :-) Both with VLC. What I really don't understand is that this quality loss appears only when exported. In the preview panel in Premiere, the image is perfect...

Comment: Check out this thread, sounds pretty similar to what you are facing: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1063696?start=0

Comment: Thank you for the link. Indeed the washed out colors seems similar to my problem but there is nothing about the more pixelated image... And besides, I'm on a PC with an AMD Radeon graphic card.
Altough I tried some of their propositions of solution but nothing worked. I just posted my problem on the topic.
I hope someone will know what matters... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will always recompress after saving in Premiere, or any other editing program. So quality loss is inevitable.

For best match to the source footage, try to export with same codec, as video was recorded.

Comment: I worked with Premiere CS5.5 for several projects and I never had such a loss of quality before. And how to find the right codec ? :-)